# Coldfusion counting looped query results from multiple datasources

Tags: arrays, struct, coldfusion

A query within a loop of a list containing multiple datasources produces records from each datasource. I would like to build a unique list of the divisions and count the number of times the division appears as it loops through the datasources.

This is working, but is there a better way using an array or struct?

```
<cfset divisions = "">

<!--- within query within loop --->

<cfif ListContains(divisions, "#SearchCompanyList.Division#")>
    <cfset variables['division#SearchCompanyList.Division#'] = variables['division#SearchCompanyList.Division#'] + 1>
<cfelse>
    <cfif Len(SearchCompanyList.Division) gt 0>
        <cfset divisions = ListAppend(divisions, "#SearchCompanyList.Division#")>
        <cfset variables['division#SearchCompanyList.Division#'] = 0>
    </cfif>
</cfif>

<!--- outside of query and loop --->

<cfloop list="#divisions#" index="div">
    <cfoutput>#div#: #Evaluate('division'&div)#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Here's a cfscript version of Tomalak's answer https://trycf.com/gist/a7362e076e3d5ab9989e694b23a5cd18/acf2021?theme=monokai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing *way* too much variable indirection. Get rid of all the `variables["#variablename#"]` and the `Evaluate()`, all of that is unnecessary. This goes for the rest of your code, I bet you can simplify it all by a lot.

For your main issue, use a struct:

```
<cfset divisionCount = StructNew('casesensitive')>

<cfloop query="SearchCompanyList">
    <cfif StructKeyExists(divisionCount, Division)>
        <cfset divisionCount[Division]++>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset divisionCount[Division] = 1>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>
<cfloop array="#StructKeyArray(divisionCount)#" item="div">
    #encodeForHTML(div)#: #divisionCount[div]#<br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

---

`StructNew('casesensitive')` is [supported from CF2021](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structnew.html). If you don't have that version yet, ColdFusion will upper-case the struct keys. Use a second struct to store the original division names, so that you can output them properly:

```
<cfset divisionCount = StructNew()>
<cfset divisionName = StructNew()>

<cfloop query="SearchCompanyList">
    <cfif StructKeyExists(divisionCount, Division)>
        <cfset divisionCount[Division]++>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset divisionCount[Division] = 1>
        <cfset divisionName[Division] = Division>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>
<cfloop array="#StructKeyArray(divisionCount)#" item="div">
    #encodeForHTML(divisionName[div])#: #divisionCount[div]#<br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

---

For side-by-side counting of multiple columns, a reusable option with a little more advanced CF would be:

```html
<cfscript>
function toGroupsBy(column) {
  return function (result, row) {
    var value = row[column];
    if (result.keyExists(value)) result[value][2]++; else result[value] = [value, 1];
    return result;
  };
}
</cfscript>

<cfset byDivision = SearchCompanyList.reduce(toGroupsBy('Division'), {})>
<cfset bySalesPerson = SearchCompanyList.reduce(toGroupsBy('SalesPerson'), {})>

<cfdump var="#byDivision#" label="Grouped by Division">
<cfdump var="#bySalesPerson#" label="Grouped by SalesPerson">

<cfoutput>
<cfloop array="#StructKeyArray(byDivision)#" item="div">
    #encodeForHTML(byDivision[div][1])#: #byDivision[div][2]#<br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

---

For nested counting, I would actually use ColdFusion's native output grouping mechanism. That ordering the query properly is necessary for this to work. Note the nested `<cfoutput>` tags.

```
<cfquery name="SearchCompanyList" datasource="mydb">
  SELECT
    Division, SalesPerson
  FROM
    MyTable 
  ORDER BY
    Division, SalesPerson
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="SearchCompanyList" group="Division">
  <cfset divCount = 0>
  <h3>#encodeForHTML(Division)#</h3>
  <ul>
    <cfoutput group="SalesPerson">
      <cfset persCount = 0>
      <cfoutput>
        <cfset persCount++>
        <cfset divCount++>
      </cfoutput>
      <li>#encodeForHTML(SalesPerson)#: #persCount#</li>
    </cfoutput>
    <li><b>Overall</b>: #divCount#</li>
  </ul>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: It's so pretty. I'd hate to push my luck, but what if I wanted to count multiple items: division, salesperson?

Comment: @sadevaadt That depends on how you want to count - side-by-side, or nested? At some point it gets easier (and faster) to let the database do the counting, though.

Comment: Nested, a count of each salesperson's records per division. ... having a terrible time finding links to learn about structs with examples (beyond the basics).

Comment: @sadevaadt I've added a "side-by-side" counting option.

Comment: @sadevaadt ...and I've added a nested counting option, too. (It's unchecked code, if it throws any errors, tell me)

Comment: Its the looping over multiple datasources that I would have to accomodate.

I was hoping for something more straight-forward that would help me visualize using structures: 

div1 100
    salesperson1 25
    salesperson2 50
    salesperson3 25
div2 50
    salesperson1 25
    salesperson2 25

Comment: @sadevaadt That's exactly what my final option does. I have no idea what you mean by "multiple datasources" but could it be that you are missing a JOIN query on the database side? It would also be possible to use query-of-queries to unify query results from different sources into one larger result that can be used this way.

Comment: (but this is getting *way* out of scope for this thread anyway. The question you asked is answered, and then some extra miles. If you have further questions, I suggest you open a new thread that focuses on a different detail.)

Comment: Just an FYI: Stop using `HTMLEditFormat()` start using `encodeForHTML()`.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno Noted. Force of habit.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me for a nested structure, expanding on Tomalak's initial answer.

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(divisionCount, 'segments')>
    <cfif StructKeyExists(divisionCount.segments, SearchCompanyList.Division)>
        <cfif StructKeyExists(divisionCount.segments[SearchCompanyList.Division], SearchCompanyList.AccountManager)>
            <cfset divisionCount.segments[SearchCompanyList.Division][SearchCompanyList.AccountManager]++>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset divisionCount.segments[SearchCompanyList.Division][SearchCompanyList.AccountManager]=1>  
        </cfif>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset divisionCount.segments[SearchCompanyList.Division][SearchCompanyList.AccountManager]=1>
    </cfif>
<cfelse>
    <cfset divisionCount.segments[SearchCompanyList.Division][SearchCompanyList.AccountManager]=1>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Two remarks: **First**, you can trim that down: inside a `<cfloop query="...">` you don't need to mention the query name all the time. You can get rid of all those `SearchCompanyList.` prefixes. **Second**, your first `<cfif>` checks for `StructKeyExists(divisionCount, 'segments')`, but the `<cfelse>` part goes on and sets `divisionCount.segments[Division][AccountManager]`. That cannot work. If `segments` does not exist as a key, the whole sub-structure is not even there. You might have something that works, but it's not this code. ;)